# javascript within php loop

Tags: php, javascript, loops

Is it possible to run javascript code within a php loop?
the javascript works perfect the problem is that it is currently not executing more than once.

```
while(...) {

 $l=$l+1;
 $linha="#x".$l;
 $linha2="x".$l;
  ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

var mensagem = "<?= $mensagem ?>";
var id= "<?= $linha ?>";

var nextMsgOptions = {
    msg:  mensagem,
    side: "bottomMiddle",       
    CSSClass: "nextMsg-LightTheme",}

$(id).click(function(){
    $(id).nextMsg(nextMsgOptions);
});


});
 </script>

}
```

any ideas? ;)

Comment: First, you can't "run" javascript code within a PHP loop because PHP is server side and javascript is client side. You can *generate* JS from PHP - is this what you mean? Secondly, please show what you are expecting as output, and what you are getting. Also, please show us what the continue condition of the `while` loop is in PHP.

Comment: i just want for every user in a table to show additional information when clicked on

Comment: OK, please show us the table, what you want to do with it, and what you are getting at the moment. Please edit the question with the HTML that is being generated at the moment, and what you would like it to be.

Comment: what i am getting is the additional information from the first guy for every one.

I'm sorry but what is the difference between javascript and JS?
I would like to try with JS

Comment: JS is short for "J"ava"S"cript.

Comment: JS and Javascript are the same.  Like @DaveRandom said, you can't execute javascript within php (normally, there's technically a way - but that doesn't apply here).  However, I understand what you're trying to accomplish - look at my response below and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can output javascript within a PHP loop, to be executed by the browser, when the page loads.

The problem here is that you've got tons of variables colliding.  You need to encapsulate each  output of that script tag in order to keep that from happening.  Here's one suggestion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php while(...): $l++; $linha = "#x" . $l; $linha2 = "x" . $l; ?>
    (function($)
    {
        var mensagem = "<?= $mensagem; ?>",
        id = "<?= $linha; ?>",
        nextMsgOptions = {
        msg: mensagem,
            side: "bottomMiddle",
            CSSClass: "nextMsg-LightTheme"
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(id).click(function(){
                $(id).nextMsg(nextMsgOptions);
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
<? endwhile; ?>
</script>
```

This keeps each `$linha` and `$mensagem` variable scoped away from each other for each iteration of the loop.  What I think is/was happening is in your old code, you'd set `$linha` to some variable, and output `id = <?= $linha; ?>` however many times your loop executed.  When `$(document).ready()` executed for each output, `$linha` had already been interpreted to be the last value that you loop output.  This caused `document.ready` to attach an event N times (N = number of iterations of your while loop) to the same DOM element (whichever the last iteration of your while loop output `$linha` to be).  With the above snippet, it keeps each `id` and `$linha` variable scoped away and private from each other, so you shouldn't have to worry about collisions.

I realize that explanation is kind of convoluted and might be hard to grok; but javascript interpretation/execution/scoping has special rules that aren't incredibly simple to convey without examples.

Comment: what does the "(jQuery)" do in the end?

Comment: and does the php while have to be inside the javascript?

Comment: WORKS! ( i just didn't put the while inside the javascript )

Comment: the `jQuery` bit at the end is just passing jQuery into the inner function.  That method creates and executes an anonymous function.  All the methods/variables inside that anonymous function are unreachable by any javascript outside the anonymous function.  Also, the `while` being inside or outside of the `<script>` tags make no difference, just ends up making more script tags in the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can:

```
<? while(...) { ?>
<script type="javascript">
// Here is you're js code
</script>
<? } ?>
```

it's be very hard to add in each container php tags.